# How to get university data by ID dynamically from user input in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an API and I want whenever the user types a university name correctly, the API gets university info by ID dynamically. I'm using get axios to get data, here's the UI image:

[image]

And here's the code I wrote so far:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Form, Button} from "react-bootstrap";
// Form, Button, Col, Row, Spinner
import axios from "axios"
import './styles.css';

function App() {

    const [institutionId, setInstitutionId] = useState("")

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let userData = {
            institutionId: institutionId
        };
        const APIKey = "API key is hidden";
        axios
            .get(`https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json?id=${institutionId}&fields=school.name,2020.student.size&api_key=${APIKey}`, JSON.stringify(userData), {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log("successfully posted to the server!!");
                } else {
                    console.log("it wasn't successful");
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
            });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));
        // setInstitutionId("");
    };

    return (
        <Container>
        <div className="App">
            <h1>University Finder App</h1>
        </div>
            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Type University Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" value={institutionId}
                                  onChange={(e) => setInstitutionId(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance for the help and let me know if I need to clarify my issue more.

Comment: The general idea is your store the response data in a state variable and use that to display it. What have you tried? FYI, `GET` requests cannot be sent with a request body from the browser so your `userData` and content-type header are redundant

Comment: using postman (or other similar tool) verified that the Harvard API returns valid json data as written, https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json?id= ...   ??

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: @LajosArpad When user type university name and click submit button it should fetch data based on that university name by using universal ID. I want the correct university name fetches data by recognizing its ID and display data to the console. Hope my question is clear. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil I also tried axios.get(), didn’t work too. I just want fetch data based on specified queries in the url. Basically, user types correct university name and api recognizes corresponding university ID and displays data on console. Let me know if still confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @MZM That API queries returns valid json when I hard coded university ID but I wanted to fetch data dynamically when user types university name by just recognizing its ID. Since university name has spaces it cannot fetch data but ID can do the work.

Comment: @MoFatah what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I follow your question and could use some clarification. Your current code seems like it would fetch data from the API when the submit button is clicked since that query is executed within the `submitHandler` function. Are you instead trying to execute the query as soon as the user types in a valid university ID in the form (i.e. without clicking the submit button)? Or is the issue with passing the university ID into the request itself? Once you answer these I might be able to help out.

EDIT: Thanks for the clarification! I would recommend first fetching the list of IDs mapped to their university names and storing that in some state (local state using `useState` is fine if you need to access this list only in this component). This could be a list like this:

```
[{ id: 1, label: 'Harvard University'}, { id: 2, label: 'Princeton' }]
```

This could be used to populate a dropdown and when user selects an option from the dropdown, the original API would be called using the id property of the option via the `onSelect` handler of the dropdown. Hope this helps.

Comment: When user type university name and click submit button it should fetch data based on that university name by using universal ID. I want the correct university name fetches data by recognizing its ID and display data to the console. Hope my question is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the api contains a huge data of University names and it’s quite hard to store them in a local state. Are there any other ways to fetch these University by just using the api. I have tested/fetched and hard coded uni ID based on url I provided and it returns data based on hard coded ID. Let me know what else I can do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user don't know the Id for the university which he want to search, I suggest to fetch all the universities from that API and store it in a list then use a `select` component with `autocomplete` fill it with the list of universities and then the user will start to type the name of a university and he will get suggestions to select from.

Comment: Autocomplete is what I eventually wanna do when user types something like “Harvard”, it should suggest “Harvard University” right away by just fetching api that corresponds to that specific university. But api contains a huge data of university names and I can’t use select. I will have to find another way to get typed university data from the API.

Comment: You should find an API that support university name instead of the id because in your scenario it's you have the university name typed by the user, and you have the api to get university by name, so the link between the two which is the id is missing.

Comment: University name will have spaces and it won’t return anything. Do you think there is a way when user types first few words of universal, the input fetches data from api and identifies that uni exist and finally returns that university info based on the url queries?

Comment: Thats why I told you, you need to find an api that takes university name as parameter